# $\forall j \in \{1,...,n-1\}$ $(\cap^j_{i=1}E_i) \cap (\cap^n_{i=j+1}E_i)=\cap^n_{i=1}E_i$. Proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given $E_1,E_2,...,E_n$ sets. Prove that $\forall j \in \{1,...,n-1\}$

$(\cap^j_{i=1}E_i) \cap (\cap^n_{i=j+1}E_i)=\cap^n_{i=1}E_i$

Here is how I thought about it:

Say x $\in (\cap^j_{i=1}E_i) \cap (\cap^n_{i=j+1}E_i)$

$\Longrightarrow x \in \cap^j_{i=1}E_i$ and $x\in (\cap^n_{i=j+1}E_i)$

$\Longrightarrow x \in \cap^j_{i=1}E_i$ and $x\in E_n$

But I don't know how to continue.

Comment: Use mathematical induction

Comment: Instead in last line of $x E_n$, write $x\in E_i$ for all $j+1\leq i\leqn$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If x is in the left hand side, then x is in
all the E's from 1 through j and
all the E's from j + 1 through n.
Thus x is in all the E's.
Hence x is in the right hand side.

If x is in the right hand side,
then x is in all the E's.  Thus x is in
all the E's from 1 through j and
all the E's from j + 1 through n.
Consequently x is in the left hand side.